Flutter Render context's widget tree;
Let's say that we have a view (page) with several widgets maybe a list of widgets, few text fields, few text widgets, etc... I would like to write a function that gets the current context and creates a map with all text values of the content...
{   
  'widget-id': 'text value',
  .
  .
  .
}

For example:

The result map should be:
{
  app-bar-id: 'Title1',
  text-id: 'Text1',
  text-field-id: 'Text-Field1'
  elevated-button-id: 'Elevated-Button1',
  text-button-id: 'Text-Button1',
}

Then, I would like to use this id and programmatically to highlight any widget if necessary;
